# Slick slider - pause on hover and play remaining seconds on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slick.js

In Slick slider i'm using the below configuration 
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

`autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 6000,
    pauseOnHover: true,
    pauseOnFocus: true,
    pauseOnDotsHover: true,`

Here, when we hover on the banner its pausing and when mouse leave again the timer is running **6000ms** again and moving to next slide.

I need like,

if we mouse hover on **3rd sec** and keep some more seconds and leave then, 
the remaining **3 seconds** only should stop and play the next slide.
How to achieve this in slick slider please.

Answer (score 1):

Finally done in **React slick slide**

We need to consider the mouse in and out time and calculate the remaining time (even in **multiple time** if the user did the mouse in and out)

In slick slide there is a option, **afterChange** and **init**

```
    init: () => {
      setSliderInitialized(true)
      addTimeStamp()
    },
    afterChange: index => {
      setCurrentSlide(index)
      setAutoplaySpeed(parseInt(props.timer)) // props.timer is pause time which is from JSON
      //setAutoplaySpeed(6000) -  6 sec  
      setTimeStamps([new Date()])
    },
```

and have to consider the mouse in and out time, for this from **React** can import **useEffect**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
```

```
  const slider = useRef()
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false)
  const previousHovered = usePrevious(hovered)
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(-1)
  const [autoplaySpeed, setAutoplaySpeed] = useState(parseInt(props.timer))
  const [timeStamps, setTimeStamps] = useState([])
  const [sliderInitialized, setSliderInitialized] = useState(false)

  const addTimeStamp = () => setTimeStamps([...timeStamps, new Date()])
```

need to use the time stamp

```
    const getElapsedTime = () => {
    let elapsedTime = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < timeStamps.length; i += 2) {
      const start = timeStamps[i]
      const stop = timeStamps[i + 1]
      elapsedTime += stop - start
    }

    return elapsedTime
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (previousHovered === false && hovered === true) {
      addTimeStamp()
    }

    if (previousHovered === true && hovered === false) {
      addTimeStamp()
      const elapsedTime = getElapsedTime()
      let remainingTime = parseInt(props.timer) - elapsedTime  // props.timer - 6000ms
      setAutoplaySpeed(remainingTime ? remainingTime : parseInt(props.timer))
    }
}, [hovered])
```

When the slider initialized `(init)` and changed `afterChange` - pass the timer.

When mouse hover store the current time and and mouse out store the time in `**array**`

By iterating the array and subtract we can get the `elapsedTime`. And we need to change the pause time from 6000ms to elapsed Time. and when slider change again we need to set the 6000ms.

Comment: you should a complete working example, because some code snippets are missing like the mouse hover and mouse out